# Songbird very slow, freezes

Tags: macos, performance, songbird

I've read on [few places](http://www.technologyblogged.com/apple/five-of-the-best-ipod-compatible-itunes-alternatives-2) that Songbird is no good with more than some thousands of library items because it starts getting quite slow.

Well, in my case ([which is a clean install](https://superuser.com/questions/63351/songbird-doesnt-start-because-of-gstreamer-in-ubuntu-9-10/63362#63362)) I've imported 17k items (which I know is not *that* much) and instead of becoming just *too slow* it frequently gets to **not responding** for several minutes until getting back to its senses again. That's for whichever random operation such as **deleting 1 item from library**.

I've also read on [few more places](http://getsatisfaction.com/songbird/topics/songbird_really_slow) that gives very little hope on fixing this issue, but I wonder...

Is there any way to tweak it and make it work as fast as expected? Am I missing something or is the software just not intended for **libraries** with more than **10 thousand** thingies?

edit: I've managed to select and *tell to remove* many, many tracks [I wanted to remove](https://superuser.com/questions/223905/filtering-itunes-library-items-by-file-location) from my library, and it's hanging on my machine for over 2 days now. I wonder how long it would take. I got just 3 more days to wait, then I'll have to turn it off to use my machine. :o

That what I meant by **really** slow! :o

2nd edit: 4 days later, I gave up on it. Decided to take my machine back 1 day earlier. Hope to see improvements at some version.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but you might not want to be passive aggressive when you're looking for help.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for the hint. Is my fix good enough? I'm not too sure where I was being "passive aggressive". I was just trying to add some humor. I'm really not **that** frustrated. This is just a minor part of my years long fight for the library.

Comment: Btw, some users on this site punish expletives (even those with the [best of intentions](http://superuser.com/questions/209374/where-can-i-find-terminal-on-os-x/209386#209386)) with downvotes. It's in your own interest to not use them.

Comment: Edited a bit. Revert if you don't like it -- just seemed like a good idea.

Comment: @Daniel thanks (as usual)! I'll try avoiding expletives while learning which ones they are. :P another question: why removed "mac" from the title?

Comment: @Cawas It's redundant (I tagged it as `osx`) and actually a little wrong (Mac no longer reasonably implies OS X). At least I hope I got your intended meaning and tagged it correctly.

Comment: @Daniel I thought OS X didn't reasonably implied mac. I at least never seem of someone buying a mac and completely excluding the X. I've noticed the tag but I figured on the title it's more explicit and less confusing. Well, anyway, it looks good. I asked about it in case it was due to something else I couldn't see. Thanks! ;)

Comment: @Cawas You're welcome. Just hover the `osx` tag above (or [click here](http://superuser.com/tags/osx/info)) and you'll see its description on SuperUser -- it's exclusively for Mac OS X. The `mac` tag ( [info](http://superuser.com/tags/mac/info) ) is for Mac hardware only.

Comment: @Daniel oh I see... maybe that's what should be fixed! OS X can be, after all, installed in other machines and it was thanks to installing it on my last PC that I decided I was going to switch to a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, Songbird is just not intended for that large a library. It'll function fine with perhaps a few thousand, but tens of thousands... probably not. It is for that reason I switched to [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) on my Windows machine, which handles my 25 thousand item library just fine and indexes and loads within the blink of an eye. I'm not sure what other players are available for osx though...

Comment: He's on Mac OS X.

Comment: I'm not really intended on using songbird as media center. I just wanted it to help cleaning up a little bit. Unfortunately there's no replacement for iTunes on the mac for too many features. But, @Blood, if you say that about songbird, I'd like some more info and / or references on to **why** it is like that. Seems counter intuitive to me such a "intended" behavior. :)

Comment: [citation needed]